# Why didn't the asgard think of other ways to survive?

Tags: stargate

In *Stargate SG-1* the Asgard died because they were losing the war with the replicators and the fact that they were clones and there bodies were failing them and they found no way to stop it plus many other reasons!

But in *Stargate SG-1* they had found many devices and technologies including the ability to travel between parallel universes. Why not use this device to see if any of the Asgards in the parallel universes had found a cure to their problem.

Additionally, they were a part of four great races that were just as smart or if not smarter than they were. I know the ancients had either died or Asended and we're unable to help, but what about the Nox or Furlings? They could have helped them with the replicators or to help they stop the cloning process.

Also, why not put most of their people in stasis pods while others protect them and hide whilst they figure out away to survive?

Finally they were cleary able to rebuild their colony after they left the Ida galaxy, why not do it again -possibly to the Pegasus galaxy? They could even go to Atlantis as the ancients had found a way to defeat the replicators and they would be able to use the knowledge of the ancients as they were far superior in technology and that they were much smarter.

It just seems like they had a lot of options to somehow survive. This just bothers me because they were my favourite characters and I just didn't get enough of them. Hahaa

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site, however this site is for asking questions. Not stating *possible* answers, you can ask the question **Why did the Asgards die?** and then answer it. As it stands I have Voted to Close as unclear what you are asking.

Comment: How do you know they didn't try everything you mentioned and fail?

Comment: it is kinda stupid they committed mass suicide.

Comment: We never see the Furlings, and to my knowledge no one mentions them as still surviving, so there's no reason to believe they were available to help. As for the Nox, it is unknown whether they could have helped, but as it was the alliance seemed to have fallen apart over time so the Asgard may not have even known the Nox were still around. The Nox did seem to like remaining invisible.

Comment: *Technically*, we did see Furlings, for a brief, thoroughly-confusing ,"WTF?!-how-did-I-miss-that-one" inducing, you-fooled-me-there few seconds, right at the beginning episode "200"

Comment: Maybe we did she the furlings and we never realised, but the when SG1 was under attack and they were able to use the device that could travel to a parallel uneverse and doing so help them fight off the goauled, the asgard could have used the same device to find the one parallel uneverse that could save them?..... it just seems like there show killed them off because it sounds good

Comment: The Asgards knew the Nox were still around, because Jack told them as much. In the episode "The Fifth Race" when the Asgards were describing the four races to him, when they mentioned the Nox's name, Jack said "met them".

Comment: Why didn't the asgard seek there help it was clear that the wear an extremely advanced race and could possibly save them from the destruction